German movie I saw on HBO with blue-ish tint to the movie
So I keep trying to remember the name of a German movie I saw awhile ago on HBO. 
It was about a few individuals that had some kind of organization. I can't remember if they were robbers or some kind of underground riot/anti-political group, all I can remember is that their plan went bad and some of them ended up in jail and one of them from what I remember killed himself (by hanging I think). 
The name was something like Kauff/Belinkoff/Underground something. 
It wasn't too old, 2000+. 
I know there's not too much to go on but I can't remember anything else, maybe just that the color scheme of the movie looked all gloomy with a cold blue-ish tint, but that's all. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing?  Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

This could be The Baader Meinhof Complex. It is a German movie from 2008 with three main characters, members of the the Red Army Faction (RAF), a left-wing terrorist group in Germany from the 1960s and 1970s.  Names of two of them were Ulrike Meinhof and Andreas Baader. They were fighting the West Germany institutions.
The title comes from the fact that the "Baader-Meinhof Group" was another name for the faction.
It's from the 2000s and seems to have a name and plot similar to what you were looking for. 
